# Encapsulation of GADT pattern matches

Tags: haskell, refactoring, pattern-matching, gadt

In this [code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/15017/16287) there are repeated fragments:

```
insert x (AATree t) = case insert' x t of
    Same t -> AATree t
    Inc t  -> AATree t

insertBlack :: (Ord a) => a -> AANode Black (Succ n) a -> AnyColor (Succ n) a
insertBlack x (Black l y r)
    | x < y     = case insert' x l of
          Same l' -> AnyColor $ Black l' y r
          Inc  l' -> AnyColor $ skew l' y r
    | otherwise = case insert' x r of
          Same r' -> AnyColor $ Black l y r'
          Inc r'  -> AnyColor $ Red   l y r'
```

So it is tempting to write a function:

```
insert2 same inc x l = case insert' x l of
          Same aa -> same aa
          Inc aa  -> inc aa
```

And use it everywhere, e.g.:

```
insert x (AATree t) = insert2 AATree AATree x t
```

Is there a way to write `insert2`? The naive approach doesn't typecheck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are case branching on a GADT, presumably the entire type of aa is not known on the outside of the case expression.  This means you need higher-rank types for the function arguments of insert2 so that they can be used at whatever type aa happens to be.

This requires {-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-} as well as an explicit type annotation for insert2.  The exact annotation needed depends on your GADT and insert' types.
Looking at your linked code I think you want something like

```
insert2 :: (Ord a) =>
    (AANode Black (Succ n) a -> b)
    -> (forall c. AANode c n a -> b)
    -> a -> AANode c n a -> b
```

Comment: Your signature is for swapped `same` and `inc` arguments but otherwise it seems to work.

Comment: @AndrewC I know, but that was a promise. I'm considering whether to fix things that aren't code bugs, though.

Comment: I rarely hold back from small edits, and I'm pretty much universally grateful when folks correct my answers. The reason the suggested edit review queue rejects code fix is that it's designed to not require reviewers to use technical understanding (same goes for diamond-moderator intervention, incidentally). Now you're trusted to make edits without review, you're trusted to fix more things. There's always rollback for people who disagree with your change, but that's rare. Nevertheless I can respect your decision to stick to your pledge even if it seemed to me that it applied to suggested edits.